# UniqueEntity on multiple fields doesn't show an error message

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, constraints, unique-constraint

I've added the following constraint to my entity:

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="link", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_link_idx", columns={"first_form_id", "first_question_id","last_form_id","last_question_id"})})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"firstForm", "firstQuestion","lastForm","lastQuestion"}, message="Cette liaison existe déjà !")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ineat\LinkQuestionBundle\Entity\LinkRepository")
```

The UniqueEntity constraint works well because before adding it, when trying to insert the exact same entity to the DB I had a DBALException abount integrity constraint.
Since then I havn't this exception anymore, the form isn't validating but `{{ form_errors(form) }}` doesn't print any message.

After having checked in the controller `$form->getErrors()` returns an empty array while `$form->getErrorsAsString()` contains the UniqueENtity constraint.

How can I have my UniqueEntity's constraint error message showing

Comment: `getErrorsAsString()` accesses the same property as `getErrors()` , namely `this->errors` in **Symfony/Component/Form/Form** , therefore `$form->getErrors()` returning an empty array is not possible. Have a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L724

Comment: Nop, it only access $this->children whereas getErrors only access errors.

Comment: well then the uniqueEntity constraint is from one of your child-forms ... you should have said that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the UniqueEntity validation seems to fail in one of your child-forms ...

(as the error message is only present in `getErrorsAsString` and not in `getErrors`)

... in order to have the child-form errors available in your parent-form use error-bubbling:

```
$formBuilder->add('child-form','child-form-type', array(
       'error_bubbling' => true,
   )
)
```

... or inside your child form:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'error_bubbling' => true,
    ));
}
```

Comment: error_bubling on my global form doesn't work, I had to add it to each child form, why?

Comment: using `->add()` or using `setDefaultOptions()` ? setDefaultOptions in the child-form of course - edited the answer to make it more clear. error-bubbling "informs" the parent forms of it's errors

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion error_bubbling should be set to true by default.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue occurs because the entity isn't binding the error message to the right field. Using the `validation.yml` file gives you more control over how and where the error message should be treated.

```
# src/Ineat/LinkQuestionBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Ineat\LinkQuestionBundle\Entity\LinkRepository:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [firstForm, firstQuestion, lastForm, lastQuestion]
            errorPath: lastQuestion
            message: 'This port is already in use on that host.'
```

More information here : [Symfony - UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

Also putting text strings into "translation" files is good practice (even if you only use/have one language). You won't have bits of text lying around in your `views / entities / forms / controllers ...` They will all be in you translation folder, in one location. Duplicate strings can also be changed all at once if necessary. It would look like this :

```
# src/Ineat/LinkQuestionBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Ineat\LinkQuestionBundle\Entity\LinkRepository:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [firstForm, firstQuestion, lastForm, lastQuestion]
            errorPath: lastQuestion
            message: 'linkquestion.form.errors.unique'

# src/Ineat/LinkQuestionBundle/Resources/translations/validators.fr.yml
linkquestion:
  form:
    errors:
      unique: "This port is already in use on that host."
# Or which ever structure you choose.
```

Then just tell your application that it will always be in French.